# If $p$ is an irreducible polynomial over a field $K$, then exists an extension $K(\alpha)\vert K$ with $\operatorname{Irr}(\alpha, K)=p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

My try:

Consider inclusion monomorphism $i:K\to K[X]$ and let's consider the ideal $I\subset K[X]$ of $p$ multiples. $I$ is a maximal ideal as $p$ is irreducible, so $S:= K[X]/I$ is a field.

On the other hand, consider $v:K[X]\to S$ the projection epimorphism. Then $v\circ i:K\to S$ is a homomorphism and it's injective? As
$$(v\circ i)(k_1)=(v\circ i)(k_2) \iff v(i(k_1))=v(i(k_2)) \iff v(k_1)=v(k_2) \iff k_1+I=k_2+I $$
where $k_i+I$ denotes the equivalence class of $k_i$ in $K[X]/I$.

As $k_1+I=\{q(x)\in K[X]: k_1-q(x)\in I\}$, we have that $k_1+I=k_2+I\iff k_1-k_2\in I$, that's to say, $k_1 - k_2 = p(x)b(x)$

Now I'd like to evaluate in some root of $p$ so we could say $k_1=k_2$. Is this possible? <<-- principal question

If we have $v\circ i$ is a monomorphism, we can see $K$ as $v(i(K))$, and taking $\alpha= X+I$, we obtain that $S=K(\alpha)$.

$p\in I\Rightarrow p(\alpha)=I$ and since $p$ is irreducible, it must be $Irr(\alpha, K)$

Is this reasoning correct? (Assuming $v\circ i$ is injective)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its simpler. As a hint:

Let $f$ be irreducible over $K$. Consider the ideal $I =\langle f\rangle$ and the quotient field $L=K[x]/I$ which is a field extension of $K$.

The polynomial $f$ has a zero in $L$, namely the residue class $\overline x  = x + I$, since $f(\overline x) = f(x) + I = I$. Put $\alpha= \overline x$. Then $f(\alpha)=0$ in $L$, and $L = K[\alpha] = K(\alpha)$ as a ring and field extension of $K$.

Comment: Why is it $L$ a field extension of $K$?, that's basically my question above. If I proof $v∘i$ is injective, I can identify $K$ with a subset of $K[X]/I $ which is a field, so it'll be a field extension. But I haven't understand yet, you just said $L$ is field extension of  $K$. I know that $L$ is a field, but now I would need to know if there exists a subset of $L$ isomorphic to $K$.

Comment: Its by construction. The elements $k+I\in L$ correspond one-to-one to $k\in K$.

Comment: The construction is $k\mapsto k+I$, but you could have $k_1\neq k_2\in K$ with $k_1+I=k_2+I$ and it wouldn't be one-to-one

Comment: It is one-to-one.

Comment: The elements of  $K[x] / I $ are given by the residue classes $p(x)+I$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $<$ degree of $f$. And two such residue classes $p(x)+I$ and $q(x)+I$ are equal iff $p(x)=q(x)$. Similar if you work with integers modulo $n$.